# IE8 weird issue with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

On this domain http://demo.acylo.com when you go to IE8 ... It loads up fine, but I'm using a jQuery script to show some buttons on hover... The problem is, right after you hover on that block of div, everything is going insane... It works fine on all the other browsers.

I tried adding float: left to that div and width: 100%, but it still doesn't work. Also in IE6/IE7 the arrows are not showing up, even if I added display: block on hover in jQuery

Comment: You have about a dozen different jQuery plugins running on that page; it wouldn't surprise me if some of them are interfering with each other. Try stripping your page down to the minimum functionality to help isolate the problem.

Comment: Seems to be a CSS issue more than anything else. Create a jsfiddle width the minimal code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Could you post the code that is causing the problem?

Comment: @b01 you can check the source code

Answer (score -1):

All IE browsers have this issue with jQuery. Especially cloning of element does not work in IE. There is a heavy use of cloning in jQuery and it works perfectly fine in all other browsers.

Custom code should be written, checking for the browser being used. Special code need to be written for IE only.